# Arduino upload fails with 'Failed uploading error. Exit Status 1'. How can I fix this?

Tags: upload, usb, port, arduino-uno

Just bought Grove Beginner kit for Arduino. I found it difficult to upload USB port driver.

I finally managed to do, not sure if I did it correctly.

The very first “Hello” sketch (Code) failed to upload: “Upload error. Failed uploading error. Exit Status 1.” I tried to remove the USB cable and reconnected. But no success. Can you advise me what to do please. My laptop runs Windows 11

My Device Manager shows the following
Ports(Com & LPT) → Arduino Leonardo (COM3)

Comment: Try restarting your computer